# windows server 2008 DHCP ran out of IP addresses

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp-server

I have a Windows 2008 server with 1 DHCP Scope 10.0.0.X/255.255.255.0 and watchguard firebox for my internet router.

I have run out of IP addresses.  I added a second scope to my DHCP server, and I can get correct IP's and internet access. The problem is I can only ping servers and not workstations. I use windows as the DNS server as well, and the entries all show up correctly as far as I can see.

Can someone help me with where to begin troubleshooting?

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the subnet on your computers from a /24 to a /23.  255.255.254.0.  On computers that have static addresses, such as your servers, you'll need to do it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

The second scope creates another network, so that any machine that receives IP addresses from that scope, is effectively on a separate network. If the router is not set up to forward ICMP packets (ping packets) to that network address, you can't ping machines that are on that network. By changing the subnet that the DHCP server hands out, it moves the IP addresses from the second scope into the same network.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. so I have to change the subnet on both dhcp scope to 255.255.254.0? In 2008 server it looks like I have to delete all scopes and recreate them? is that correct?  Thanks

Comment: Just delete the existing scopes and recreate one new one as a /23. I don't see any reason for having two scopes for what is essentially one network.

Comment: what happens to existing leases? will they be able to communicate?  Should I change the lease time to 1 hour and wait for the existing to run out?